# APP Running on IOS 6 crashes in IOS 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Hi i have App where it works fine when i run in ios 6 and Above,whereas when i run the same app in IOS 5 and 4.3 the App crashes i get the Following Error.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSUUID

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_nonatomic_copy

Referenced from: /Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/EE819847-D72F-42AA-B27B-58E8692A4069/CollectionView_dfm.app/CollectionView_dfm

  Expected in: /Desktop/xcode 4.6/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation

 in Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/EE819847-D72F-42AA-B27B-58E8692A4069/CollectionView_dfm.app/CollectionView_dfm
```

I Googled it but i didnt understand what exactly the problem is.Even i saw few people answered telling make the Foundation Framework Optional and change deployment Target to IOS 5,But i tried still i am not able to solve this issue.Can anyone please Help me in Solving this Issue.

Note:I am using UICollectionview. To support less than IOS 6 i am using Library Called PSTCollectionview.
https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView

Comment: no its was running as i am using Library to support for IOS 5 and 4.3 i.e, PSTCollectionView 
https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView

Comment: `NSUUID` is only available in iOS 6 and later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple's docs, NSUUID was added to iOS 6.0. Thus it won't be available in iOS 5.0.

If you're not using NSUUID yourself, you might want to look through the library you're using and see if IT is using it. If you have the source for the library it should be easy to find. It should be possible to modify the code to check for the NSUUID class and use CFUUID instead if NSUUID is unavailable.

Comment: ok i was able to fix that.Once i fix that i am getting this error 
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_nonatomic_copy

Comment: how exactly did you fixed that ?

Comment: Ok, if you're having a new problem it's time to start a new question thread where you post a complete description of the problem.